# How to convert video (from mobile storage) to base64 in react native?

Tags: react-native, video, base64

I am getting video from mobile local storage through ImagePicker in react native, now I want to convert this video to base64 but unable to do it.

Implemented code is:

```js
ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(
  { mediaType: 'video', includeBase64: true },
  (response) => {
    try {
      RNFetchBlob.fs
        .stat(response.assets[0].uri)
        .then((res) => {
          //"res.path" will give me original path of video.
        })
        .catch((err) => {});
    } catch (Excepstion) {}
  }
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout the [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) package. and use that like:

```js
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
...

// readFile(filepath: string, encoding?: string)
RNFS.readFile(filePath, 'base64').then(res => {
    ...
})
.catch(err => {
    ...
    console.log(err.message, err.code);
    ...
});
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: App is crashing when i am trying to implement this